# How to read rows of this csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am facing problem, while reading csv file.

csv format:
The following is the format for two entries in csv file:

```
    "1", "one", "<long class=\"like\" >\
    <short class=\"over\">\
    </short>
    </long>", "3", "<long class=\"like\" >\
    <short class=\"over\">\
    </short>
    </long>", "facebook"
    "2", "two", "<long class=\"like\" >\
    <short class=\"over\">\
    </short>
    </long>", "3", "<long class=\"like\" >\
    <short class=\"over\">\
    </short>
    </long>", "facebook"
```

How to read each row in this kind of csv file?

Comment: it's a strange content as for csv file. And how should look the expected result?

Comment: Should there be 4 spaces in front of every line, or is that  formatting problem?

Comment: stackoverflow format there is no spaces before line

Comment: I cannot sniff a valid delimiter-quotechar combo that would read this as two records.

Comment: delimiter as "," and record separate with new line

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use `csv` package?

You could read each line and play with it like you want, for example:

```
import csv
with open('prueba.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        <That you want to do with each row>
```

But maybe you want to do another different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that some two entries from your *csv* file look like below:

```
"1", "one", "<long class=\"like\" ><short class=\"over\"></short></long>", "3", "<long class=\"like\" ><short class=\"over\"></short></long>" "facebook"
"2", "two", "<long class=\"like\" ><short class=\"over\"></short></long>", "3", "<long class=\"like\" ><short class=\"over\"></short></long>" "facebook"
```

Consider using `re.findall()` function:

```
import re 

with open('test.csv', 'r') as fh:
    lines = fh.read().split('\n')
    for l in lines:
        fields = re.findall(r'^\"(\d+)\", \"(\w+)\", (.+)', l, re.S)
        a, b, c = fields[0]   # unpacking fields
        print(a, b, c, sep='\t')
```

The output:

```
1   one "<long class=\"like\" ><short class=\"over\"></short></long>", "3", "<long class=\"like\" ><short class=\"over\"></short></long>" "facebook"
2   two "<long class=\"like\" ><short class=\"over\"></short></long>", "3", "<long class=\"like\" ><short class=\"over\"></short></long>" "facebook"
```